# What is an idiomatic way to specify a matplotlib figure and axes to a function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

What I'm trying to do could be written like this:

```
import pylab
class GetsDrawn(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=some_function_that_returns_an_array()
        self.y=some_other_function_that_returns_an_array()

    # verison 1: pass in figure/subplot arguments
    def draw(self, fig_num, subplot_args ):
        pylab.figure(fig_num)
        pylab.subplot( *subplot_args )
        pylab.scatter( self.x, self.y)
```

i.e. I could tell the object "where" to draw itself via a figure-number and sub-plot configuration.

I suspect that a version which is passed a pylab object would be more flexible in the 
long run, but don't know what type of object(s) to provide to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scripts, it is generally preferred to use the object oriented api.

For example, you can let your function receive a figure:

```
def draw(fig, sub_plot_args,x,y):
    ax = fig.subplot(*sub_plot_args)
    ax.scatter(x,y)
```

If your function actually draws only on one axes, you can even pass that as an object:

```
def draw(ax,x,y):

    ax.scatter(x,y)
```

To create a figure use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
```

and to create for example a figure with one subplot on it, use:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

The last command only exists in recent versions if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

I would initialize all the axes in `__init__`. Save them in a list, e.g. `self.ax`. Then in the `draw` method, you could send draw commands directly to the desired axes object:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class GetsDrawn(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=some_function_that_returns_an_array()
        self.y=some_other_function_that_returns_an_array()
        self.ax = []
        for i in range(num_figures):
            fig = plt.figure(i)
            self.ax.append(plt.subplot(1, 1, 1))

    # verison 1: pass in figure/subplot arguments
    def draw(self, fig_num, subplot_args ):
        ax = self.ax[fig_num]
        ax.subplot( *subplot_args )
        ax.scatter( self.x, self.y)
```

By the way, `pylab` is okay for interactive sessions, but `pyplot` is [recommend for scripts](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pylab-and-pyplot-how-are-they-related).